# Partial Selection in JTree using checkbox for every node

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a application which uses a JTree. For each node in the tree, there is a checkbox attached to the node using a customized TreeCellRenderer. When some items of a node are selected i.e not all children of a node are selected using the chechboxes, how do i indicate using the checkbox of the parent node that only a partial list of nodes is selected. For this, i need to draw a little square in the checkbox indicating that it is partially selected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use e.g.
http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/tristatecheckbox.shtml or
http://www.javaspecialists.co.za/archive/Issue082.html

Comment: I think this example is better than Java2s: http://www.jroller.com/santhosh/entry/jtree_with_checkboxes